# Does a laptop have any hot swap risk when using a docking station?

Tags: laptop, docking-station, hotswapping, hotplug

Certain computer ports (such as PS/2, serial, parallel, VGA) are not hot swappable and there is a risk (maybe a low risk, but still a risk nonetheless) of damage if you disconnect a device from one of those ports while the computer is powered on.

I am getting ready to buy a laptop along with a docking station, and I am planning on using the PS/2, parallel, and VGA ports on the docking station.  Would the laptop have the same risk of damage if I undock it while it is powered on and those ports are in use?  Or would the docking station shield the laptop from any possible damage?  If the latter is the case, would the docking station itself have any risk of damage?